# What happens if a local variable loses its scope after being put into a channel?

Tags: for-loop, go, scope, channel

Especially when the variable is generated inside a local scope. How long is its survival time?

For example, given a loop creates 10 dogs and pass the pointers along into a channel, like

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    dogAddr := produce(i)    // assume we already have: func produce(i int) *Dog 
    c <- dogAddr             // c: channel
}
```

When the loop ends, will the dogs be released immediately? will they survive only for a magic time to wait for being consumed, and Will they be released after being consumed?

I tested this in a simple code, and results seems to show that the local variables will survive forever.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)
func main() {
    var a int
    var c chan *int = make(chan *int, 1000)
    var m map[int]*int = make(map[int]*int)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {                     // this is generation-loop
        x := i
        m[i] = &x
        fmt.Println(i, "mapping to: ", &a)
        c <- &x
    }                                            // the generation-loop breaks here
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i, "stored pointer: ", m[i]) // we can still call the variables 
    }
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i, "stored value: ", *m[i])  // we can still call the variables 
        p := <-c
        fmt.Println(i, "channel value: ", *p)    // we can still call the variables 
    }
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)

}
```

I am very confused on why this could happens. Aren't local variables lose their life as long as local blocks get finished? If the way I used is wrong, then what is the correct way to pass local variables to an outer user in Go?

Comment: Channels aren't special; passing a value over a channel is the same as passing it as a function argument or in an assignment statement. It's unclear what your question is about really, but it seems like your confusion is around pointers. When you pass a pointer to a value, anything that modifies the value being pointed at will impact anything that has a pointer to the same value.

Comment: A variable is live if there's a way to access the variable. Blocks control scope, not lifetime.

Comment: When you take the address of `x` by writing `&x` the garbage collector will know and make sure `x` stays around for as long as the `*int` pointing to it is *reachable*. The only way to break this using Go itself is to write `foo := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x))` and retain the value until an indeterminate point in the future where `*x` is freed and then trying to access `*(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(foo))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go is garbage collected. Resources are freed when there are no more references to them, including references currently held in buffered channels. You don't have to worry about use-after-free, and there is nothing wrong with returning/sending pointers to "local" variables.

> Aren't local variables lose their life as long as local blocks get finished?

No, they "lose their life" when the garbage collector finds no further references to their value. Variables that outlive their enclosing scope are automatically allocated on the heap and are safe to use after flow returns from the enclosing scope and its stack memory is lost.

Think of it this way: There is no such thing in Go as a "local" variable that outlives its scope. That is impossible. A variable that lives beyond the scope in which it is declared is by definition not "local" in that sense, it is automatically moved to the heap and lives as long as anything continues to reference it.

Something worth expanding on:

> ```
> for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
>    dogAddr := produce(i)    // assume we already have: func produce(i int) *Dog 
>    c <- dogAddr             // c: channel
> }
> ```
>
> When the loop ends, will the dogs be released immediately?

Your confusion seems to stem either from the idea that the `dogAddr` variable itself is somehow synonymous with the memory it points to, or from the mistaken idea that the `dogAddr` pointer going out of scope would somehow cause the memory it points to to be reclaimed while other things still point to it, which isn't true in any language, garbage collection or not.

The `dogAddr` pointer just contains an address. That variable *does* go out of scope each iteration of the loop, but the the value it holds (the address of a `Dog` object on the heap) has already been copied by value into the channel. Yes, `dogAddr` is a "local" variable, but that's not really relevant. Its value is not "local", its value is a memory address for some non-local `Dog` object allocated down inside `process()`.

> I tested this in a simple code, and results seems to show that the local variables will survive forever.

No, you've just shown that, as long as you have a reference to a bit of memory, that memory will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks. According to what you said, is it possible for an endless for-loop to generate too much variables and become stack overflow? How to avoid this?

Comment: You cannot create arbitrary numbers of stack-allocated variables in (AFAIK) any language. If you're dynamically creating things, they go on the heap. You can exhaust the heap but that's a different problem, and possible in any language.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't caused by declaring too many variables, that would be out-of-memory. Yes, it's always possible to consume more memory than is available, but the only way to do that in a loop would be appending to a slice or a map; variables declared inside a loop are scoped to the loop iteration and don't persist into the next iteration.

Comment: Your answer is very clear and perfect, and you have exactly pointed out my confusion. Thanks.

Comment: *There is no such thing in Go as a "local" variable that outlives its scope.*  Not quite right; scope != lifetime. There can be local variables (variables declared in functions) that are no longer in scope when the function returns but do live on because a reference to them still exists.

Comment: @jub0bs Yes, this is exactly what I said in my answer.